# Javascript with Python Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, compatibility, clock

I have a HTML web server with CSS. I want to have a digital clock and I believe the script should be in a .js file for javascript and I have to include or run that from my HTML web page. **How should I do this and how come having a separate JavaScript file with even just `alert("This is from JavaScript!");` doesn't work?**

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you referenced the .js file in your HTML code such as:

```
  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Should that go in the header?

Comment: When I do that I get an error in the html console: HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). GET - http://192.168.0.6:5000/script.js

Comment: It means that the path to the script.js file is not correct. Be sure that script.js exists in the root folder of your web application.

Comment: Oh, ok I have fixed that but now I get a syntax error at line 1,1 I get this in the console: <html>
<body>
alert("Welcome To ThePGT's Website");
</body>
</html>
But in my main.js file it is just alert("Welcome To ThePGT's Website"); and I have saved the file.